# Implementing Algorithm Syntax Error

Tags: shell, unix

```
#!/bin/ksh
extended_gcd() 
{
  a=$1
  b=$2
  x=0;
  lastx=1;
  y=1;
  lasty=0;
  while ((b!=0));
  do
    quotient=$a/$b
    tmp3$b
    b=$(($a%$b))
    a=$tmp3
    tmp3=$x
    $x=$lastx-$quotient*$x
    $lastx=$tmp3
    tmp3=$y
    $y=$lasty-$quotient*$y
    $lasty=$tmp3
  done
  echo $lastx $lasy
}
var = $(extended_gcd $1 $2)
echo $var
```

Hi guys,

Recently, I have a problem with the implementation of the following codes on Unix. I couldn't manage to find the syntax errors here. I will be really grateful if you could check this code and help me correct it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Thanks for formatting your code properly.  The more specific you are about what's going wrong with the code -- basically, the more effort you do before asking your question -- the more receptive the community will be to help you.

Comment: As John said, welcome. :-) This is not really a site for "Here's a bunch of code. Please figure out what it's supposed to do and fix it for me." posts. Please [edit] your question to explain *specifically* what the problem is you're having with it, so we can try and help you solve it. Asking us to figure out what's wrong before we can try and help you is just inconsiderate. At least put in the effort to actually ask us a question before expecting us to spend our time helping you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the script in **debug mode** `-x` and you should be able to resolve it yourself.

From the initial look I see quite a lot of issues. I've tried to clean up as I went through each line but its not tested. So you should be able to resolve it by running it in debug mode.

```
#!/bin/ksh -x

extended_gcd() {
        a=$1
        b=$2
        x=0;
        lastx=1;
        y=1;
        lasty=0;
        while [[ $b != 0 ]]; do
                quotient=$(($a / $b))
                tmp3=$b
                b=$(($a % $b))
                a=$tmp3
                tmp3=$x
                x=$(($lastx - $quotient * $x))
                lastx=$tmp3
                tmp3=$y
                y=$(($lasty - $quotient * $y))
                lasty=$tmp3
        done
        echo $lastx $lasty
}

extended_gcd $1 $2
```